# Run a subcommand inside a context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

In the context of a python `click` CLI application, I would like to run a subcommand inside of a context manager that would be setup in a higher level command. How is it possible to do that with `click`? My pseudo-code looks something like:

```py
import click

from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def database_context(db_url):
    try:
        print(f'setup db connection: {db_url}')
        yield
    finally:
        print('teardown db connection')


@click.group
@click.option('--db',default='local')
def main(db):
    print(f'running command against {db} database')
    db_url = get_db_url(db)
    connection_manager = database_context(db_url)
    # here come the mysterious part that makes all subcommands
    # run inside the connection manager

@main.command
def do_this_thing()
    print('doing this thing')

@main.command
def do_that_thing()
    print('doing that thing')
```

And this would be called like:

```sh
> that_cli do_that_thing
running command against local database
setup db connection: db://user:pass@localdb:db_name
doing that thing
teardown db connection

> that_cli --db staging do_this_thing
running command against staging database
setup db connection: db://user:pass@123.456.123.789:db_name
doing this thing
teardown db connection
```

Edit: note that the above example is forged to better illustrate the missing functionality of `click`, not that I want to solve this problem in particular. I know I could repeat the same code in all commands and achieve the same effect, which I already do in my real use case. My question is precisely on what could I do **only** in the main function, that would run all transparently subcommands in a context manager.

Comment: Context mangers where designed to operate in conjuction with Python's [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement, but you're not using one to wrap a block of code (so it doesn't work).

Comment: I know, that's the root of the problem. By the nature of the click framework, there is no place in the `main` command where a subcommand is explicitely called. The call is done by the framework, depriving me of the possibility to use the context manager in a `with` statement.

Comment: How would you like the sub commands to access `db`?  Passed into the sub commands or available through some sort of global?

Comment: @StephenRauch through a global DB object, that only works correctly inside an application and database context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This use case is supported natively in Click from v8.0 by using
`ctx.with_resource(context_manager)`

https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/#click.Context.with_resource

There is a worked example in the Click advanced documentation

https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/advanced/#managing-resources

Answer (score 4):

#### Decorating commands

1. Define a context manager **decorator** using [`contextlib.ContextDecorator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator)
2. Use [`click.pass_context`](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/#nested-handling-and-contexts) decorator on `main()`, so you can explore click context
3. Create an instance `db_context` of the context manager
4. Iterate on commands defined for group `main` using `ctx.command.commands`
5. For each command, replace the original callback (function called by the command) with the same callback decorated with the context manager `db_context(cmd)`

This way you will programmatically modify each command to behave just like:

```
@main.command()
@db_context
def do_this_thing():
    print('doing this thing')
```

But without requiring to change your code beyond your function `main()`.

See the code below for a working example:

```
import click
from contextlib import ContextDecorator


class Database_context(ContextDecorator):
    """Decorator context manager."""

    def __init__(self, db_url):
        self.db_url = db_url

    def __enter__(self):
        print(f'setup db connection: {self.db_url}')

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print('teardown db connection')


@click.group() 
@click.option('--db', default='local')
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx, db):

    print(f'running command against {db} database')
    db_url = db  # get_db_url(db)

# here come the mysterious part that makes all subcommands
# run inside the connection manager

    db_context = Database_context(db_url)           # Init context manager decorator
    for name, cmd in ctx.command.commands.items():  # Iterate over main.commands
        cmd.allow_extra_args = True                 # Seems to be required, not sure why
        cmd.callback = db_context(cmd.callback)     # Decorate command callback with context manager


@main.command()
def do_this_thing():
    print('doing this thing')


@main.command()
def do_that_thing():
    print('doing that thing')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It does what you describe in your question, hope it will work as expected in real code.

---

#### Using [`click.pass_context`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/#nested-handling-and-contexts).)

This code below will give you an idea of how to do it using `click.pass_context`.

```
import click
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def database_context(db_url):
    try:
        print(f'setup db connection: {db_url}')
        yield
    finally:
        print('teardown db connection')


@click.group()
@click.option('--db',default='local')
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx, db):
    ctx.ensure_object(dict)
    print(f'running command against {db} database')
    db_url = db #get_db_url(db)
    # Initiate context manager
    ctx.obj['context'] = database_context(db_url)

@main.command()
@click.pass_context
def do_this_thing(ctx):
    with ctx.obj['context']:
        print('doing this thing')

@main.command()
@click.pass_context
def do_that_thing(ctx):
    with ctx.obj['context']:
        print('doing that thing')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(obj={})
```

Another solution to avoid explicit `with` statement could be passing the context manager as a decorator using [`contextlib.ContextDecorator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator), but it would likely be more complex to setup with `click`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but using the context manager in every sub-command is exactly the goal of the whole thing. My real use-case is to have many commands doing things with the database in a transparent way, and using the context manager only once in the main command.

Comment: Not sure it can be done, at least not if you create a context in the local scope of main(), because you will exit this context before executing the command.
Maybe click is not the way to go to achieve this?

Comment: @AntoineGallix Finally found how to proceed! This problem ate me all day, took me a while to figure how to properly and simply modify how the commands are called. This is definitely more a hack than a best practice, but it works.

Comment: Great solution! I was hoping for a dedicated feature of click, but apparently it doesn't exist, so your solution fill this gap. Thanks.

Comment: looking at the new answer from @ross-g, it seems that that exact same functionality have been introduced now.